# Libraries and their path require for the Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-7

I am new to Jasper Reports. I have just installed i-report 4.5.1 and wants to include the library of ( jasper-report) to my Project.I  have searched a lot for this work. Please guide me which .jar files i need to include in my project and where these files are located in the installatin of i-report 4.5.1.Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) (e.g. jasperreports-4.5.1-project.zip). The samples there make it clear what you need. That will be far better than trying to reverse engineer what iReport does.

Comment: please provide samples for jasper reports.